# if there is a infinite loop in a python code, is it harmful or use large amount of resources?

Tags: python, time, infinite-loop, busy-waiting

i am trying to make an alarm clock. this uses the time function and check if current time is equal to the alarm time in a while True loop.
does it use heavy amount of resources as it check the condition at the maximum frequency it can. is there a way to reduce this frequency so that less processing load is applied to the processor.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `time.sleep()`. The phenomenon that you're (correctly) trying to avoid is called [busy-waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting).

For example, if you wanted to set a ten second delay, you wouldn't want to do:

```py
import time

start = time.time()
while time.time() - start <= 10:
    pass
```

Instead, you'd want to do:

```py
import time
time.sleep(10)
```